# Preprocessor DEF can not be conditioned inside IF, ELIF and ELSE statement in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to use `DEF` inside the `IF` pre-processor statement in Cython. The equivalent code in C is:

```
#define A 1
#if A == 1
    #define B 2
#else
    #define B 3
#endif
```

The expected value of `B` is `2`. But in Cython it is not. Suppose

```
# in Definitions.pxi
DEF A=1
IF A==1:
    DEF B=2
    print('B should be 2.')
ELSE:
    DEF B=3
    print('B should be 3.')
```

In a test file:

```
# In test.pyx
include "Definitions.pxi"
print('B is: %d'%B)
```

Compiled with:

```
# In setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(name = "test",ext_modules = cythonize(Extension("*",["test.pyx"])))
```

Now, testing it:

```
>>> ipython
In [1]: %reload_ext Cython
In [2]: import test

B should be 2
B is: 3
```

It seems that the very last `DEF` is effective and all `IF` as well as `ELIF` and `ELSE` are ignored. Is this a normal behavior or a bug?